# Add onDraw drawable on top of main.xml

Tags: android, image, view, android-activity, ondraw

I am new to Android development and I am having a problem figuring out how to add a drawn line on top of an image. I can draw the line and display it, or I can display the image, but I can't figure out how to display both at the same time.

Consider an anolog speedometer guage. In main.xml I have an ImageView which displays an image of the speedometer minus the needle. For the needle, I want to programmatically draw a line and add it on top of the gauge image.

Here is my activity and view code:

```
public class StartDraw extends Activity {
    DrawView drawView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
        setContentView(new DrawView(this));

    }

    final class DrawView extends View {
        Paint paint = new Paint();

        public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

            canvas.drawLine(30, 100, 150, 200, paint);
        }
     }   
}
```

and here is my main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/image" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

How do I display the needle on top of the speedometer? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to break DrawView out into a separate class file.  You can then add it as an element inside your main.xml's LinearLayout.

After you call `setContentView(R.layout.main);`, you can get a reference to the DrawView instance in your Activity by doing:

```
DrawView dv = (DrawView)findViewById(R.id.drawView); //use the actual id you define in your layout xml
```

Comment: Instead of using "canvas.drawLine(30, 100, 150, 200, paint);", I will be using something like "canvas.drawLine(startx, starty, stopx, stopy, paint);" with startx,starty, stopx, and stopy calculated in my main activity. If I break DrawView out into a separate class file, how do I use the values calculated in my main activity to update the coordinates used in DrawView's drawLine?

Comment: I edited my question to show how you get a reference to the DrawView instance.  At that point, you can pass information over to it.